# Detect if Always-On is enabled from settings on Android Wear

Tags: android

Any idea how can I detect of Always-On setting is enabled in Android Wear?
I want to check this so I know should I update information in onVisibilityChanged or in onAmbientModeChanged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just check what the current watch mode is. Also, check out `onEnterAmbient`, `onExitAmbient`, `onUpdateAmbient`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/activity/WearableActivity.html