# Android, Wear OS. Detect Always-On-Display is on/off

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung, always-on-display

I'm trying to understand how you can determine that Always-On-Display mode is on/off. Before starting my process, I must know whether this option is selected in advance in the device's system menu. In the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216558/detect-always-on-display-when-trying-to-determine-if-the-screen-is-off) (another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651345/detect-if-always-on-is-enabled-from-settings-on-android-wear)), one way or another was given the answer, but this is not a direct way to identify it and it is limited in application.

Is there a way to understand whether the Always-On-Display (AOD) option is enabled in Android and in particular Wear OS?

I use Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 (SM-R860). I also did not find a way to understand this using Samsung's SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Activity:

```java
try {
    boolean ambientEnabled = Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), "ambient_enabled") == 1;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handler
}
```